# Can't Connect to Tor Network, failed to Establish Network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, help

I'm trying to browse tor on my university wifi, but whenever I try to connect, it doesn't connect after a long time. I've used some bridges and it still can't connect.

Log:
1/31/2017 10:31:11 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

1/31/2017 10:31:11 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

1/31/2017 10:31:11 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

1/31/2017 10:31:11 AM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

1/31/2017 10:31:17 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

1/31/2017 10:31:17 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

1/31/2017 10:31:38 AM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.73.235.50:56391 ("general SOCKS server failure")

1/31/2017 10:31:38 AM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 94.242.249.2:57860 ("general SOCKS server failure")

1/31/2017 10:31:38 AM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.208.239:28548 ("general SOCKS server failure")

Comment: Likely some kind of censorship. Try other bridges (obfs4 or meek), otherwise find some other method to tunnel Tor over that bypasses their censorship (iodine, ssh, vps, etc).

Comment: @canonizingironize it seems that an upstream proxy uses by-ip allowed list, so pluggable transports may not help, but it's worth a try

Comment: You're just making stuff up again, Alexey. You have no evidence to support that claim.